# Video treatment in Visual Studio with Emgu cv in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, video, emgucv

I am currently working on a project where I have to do real-time video treatment.  The first step consists in binarizing the video.

I am using Visual studio with Emgu cv, I've never done c# before so I am struggling a little.

I have a problem with opening a video in a Windows Form. I found how to do it in a Windows Media Player but I can't binarize the video inside the Windows Media Player.

I found a tutorial on Youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdjoutNR2DQ) which explains how to binarize a Webcam feed in an ImageBox, but I can't find a way to do this with a video I have on my computer (.wmv).

Thank You for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code of the video link you have provided uses the following line to access the live default web cam feed.

```
Capture capWebCap = new Capture();
```

You can use the following line to open a video file.

```
Capture video = new Capture("your_file_name.wmv");
```

Check the documentation for the Capture constructor [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/5edc4ff8-cec3-c5ee-8e62-629cf4c7940a.htm). I believe everything else shown is that code in video can be used more or less unchanged.
Hope this helps.